# Картография онлайн игры

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток! Возник вопрос, как лучше хранить карту в онлайн игре (90 секторов для каждого игрока, с уникальным статусом для каждого сектора) в БД MySQL. Заранее спасибо!

Решение: хранить сериализованный массив. Всем спасибо!

Comment: - Статус меняется от действия игроков?

- Если нет, то засериализуйте и запихните каждый сектор или сразу всю карту в `BLOB.`

Comment: Да, меняется.

Comment: @Indev

- Если карта небольшая, а статусов каждой клетки немного, то я замапил бы все возможные стейты, например, на `int` и хранил бы их для каждого игрока.

- Хотя, в общем-то, правильный и универсальный подход, здесь, разумеется, заключается в том, чтобы хранить засериализованный `BLOB` и проводить `pack-unpack` при необходимости изменений. Все остальное попахивает `premature optimization`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлогаю хранить массив карты в сериализованном виде

Comment: согласен, тем более что там ферма, можно будет зранить даже в vatchar

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется если карта статична - то хранить ее в игроке нет смысла (если игра онлайн и многопользовательская), если же у каждого игрока своя карта - то это уже противоречит здравой логике. Могу предположить, что хранится не карта, а некие объекты на ней, идентификаторы выполненных заданий ...

Я бы хранил карту в 1 месте и в зависимости от действий игроков апдейтил ее.

Comment: Скажем так, у каждого игрока в секторе есть ферма, она также поделена на секторы, в каждом из которых изменяется обстановка (после полива допустим) в зависимости от действий игрока.